# how Add image's name on the image menu

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I'm using Magento 1.9.1
I wondering whether can I add name of image(file's name) to image menu ?
I need to double check my images with specific color and i can verify them only by file name so if i could add title on that menu which is showing my file names will be great.